nvpmodel fails in Yocto Kirkstone on Xavier NX
nvpmodel fails with:
NVPM ERROR: Error opening /sys/devices/platform/13e10000.host1x/15810000.se/acm/clk_cap/se: 2

As above path does not exist on the platform.
I need a starting point to investigate and it seems that determining which driver is responsible to create that path would be a good start... unless it is something I omitted in the dts ...
An help appreciated as I am quite stuck on that one
Thanks
need a starting point to that investigation
